# Get first element in a for..in two dimension

Tags: javascript, json

i have a Json object that basicly is a array and in each array i want to iterate over the propertys, so i did something like this:

```
for(var x = 0;x<dados.feeds.length;x++){
        for(var y in dados.feeds[x]){
            console.log(dados.feeds[x][y]);
            /*if(data == dataInicial){
                console.log("a");
            }*/
        }
    }
```

that console.log(`dados.feeds[x][0]`) gives me undefined, i just want the first element on each x row, how can i get it ?

**json object dados**

```
{
  "channel":
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "my_house",
    "description": "Netduino Plus connected to sensors around the house",
    "latitude": "40.44",
    "longitude": "-79.996",
    "field1": "Light",
    "field2": "Outside Temperature",
    "created_at": "2010-12-13T20:20:06-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00",
    "last_entry_id": 6060625
  },
  "feeds":
  [
    {
      "created_at": "2014-02-26T12:42:49-05:00",
      "entry_id": 6060624,
      "field1": "188",
      "field2": "25.902335456475583"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00",
      "entry_id": 6060625,
      "field1": "164",
      "field2": "25.222929936305732"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: hard to comment without seeing what `dados.feeds` looks like

Comment: edited the question

Comment: it should be `console.log(dados.feeds[x].created_at);`

Comment: oh, i get it now. you can't access the first property in the objects inside the feeds array as objects aren't sorted. `y` in `for(var y ..)` gives you the objects key, so `created_at`, `entry_id` and so on. `console.log(dados.feeds[x].created_at);` would give you what you want

Comment: so why you use outer loop if you want get only `feeds`? Iterate in `dados.feeds` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as you have it runs fine, everything traces out, nothing is undefined (I tried it).

But, console.log[x][0] will trace undefined, because:

```
var x = 0;
var obj = feeds[x]; // this will be the first object from the feeds array.
console.log ( obj [ 0 ] );
```

You probably see it now; that will trace undefined, because that obj has no 0 property. It's an object with keys/values.

So this would work:

```
var each = 'created_at';
console.log ( obj [ each ] );
```

And this:

```
for ( var each in obj ) {
   console.log ( each, obj [ each ] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your data looks like? If it's similar to

```
var dados = {
  feeds: [ {a: 'aa'}, {b: 'bb'} ]
}
```

then you can try this:

```
dados.feeds.forEach(feed => {
  Object.keys(feed).forEach((key, index) => {
    if(index === 0) { console.log(feed[key]) } // aa bb...
  })
})
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

It should be `console.log(dados.feeds[x].created_at);`.

Answer (score 0):

Although [you shouldn't rely on Javascript object key order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), here is a solution that will return the value of the first key in each entry in the feeds array;

```
var dados = {
  "channel":
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "my_house",
    "description": "Netduino Plus connected to sensors around the house",
    "latitude": "40.44",
    "longitude": "-79.996",
    "field1": "Light",
    "field2": "Outside Temperature",
    "created_at": "2010-12-13T20:20:06-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00",
    "last_entry_id": 6060625
  },
  "feeds":
  [
    {
      "created_at": "2014-02-26T12:42:49-05:00",
      "entry_id": 6060624,
      "field1": "188",
      "field2": "25.902335456475583"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00",
      "entry_id": 6060625,
      "field1": "164",
      "field2": "25.222929936305732"
    }
  ]
};

var con = document.getElementById('console');
for (var i = 0; i < dados.feeds.length; i++) {
    var firstKey = Object.keys(dados.feeds[i])[0];
    con.innerHTML += '<p>' + dados.feeds[i][firstKey] + '</p>';
}

/*
Prints;

2014-02-26T12:42:49-05:00

2014-02-26T12:43:04-05:00

*/
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f26uwot0/) is a fiddle with the working code.